Excel calculating different dates using same formula, between server and local installation
I work with Excel files which I prepare on a server and then copy locally so that they can be emailed out. I've found that after I copy the finished files to my local machine, the installation of Excel on my local machine must interpret dates differently from the installation on the server.

Microsoft® Excel® 2016 (16.0.5443.1000) MSO (Version 2402 Build 16.0.5443.1001) 32-bit

Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2402 Build 16.0.17328.20282) 64-bit
In both files the referenced J4 cell contains the date 05/01/2024. The server appears to be American and thinks that this is the 1st of May, while my machine must be British and sees the 5th of January. I'm based in the UK but working with American software so the cell should indeed be interpreted as the 1st of May. In any case I would just like it to be consistent so that I can prepare my files and email them out.

Is J4 actually a date, or is it a text value that looks like a date? The first thing I would check is to ensure that the value of J4 is being stored in the cell as a date and not a text value. Also, it is probably better to use cell formatting to get the date format you want, rather than TEXT(), because the function produces a string data type rather than a date data type.

Thanks for answering. It's just text that looks like a date. But that's how the data is output and what I have to work with. And Excel manages to interpret it correctly as a date for EOMONTH, it just interprets it differently between my different installations of Excel.
You're right about TEXT, I'll change to proper date formatting for those cells.

Yeah, that's going to be your problem. EOMONTH is implicitly converting the text to a date data type. On the server, it is using American regional settings to do the conversion. On your machine, it is using British regional settings to make the conversion. If you cannot change the source, you're going to have to explicitly convert the date using string manipulation and the DATE function. It sucks, but it's probably the only way, unless you change your local machine to be American.

I'll have to write something cumbersome to take the string apart and force it into the right format - thanks for the idea. I don't suppose you know how to change Excel's default expectation of date formats?

I think it uses the machine's regional settings. I don't know if there is a way to override that. There may also be a function that allows you to specify the date format when converting from a string. I don't know that either. Always many ways to solve an issue.

I'm curious to know what CELL will return for J4 when the file is viewed on the server and locally. If you have time, could you post the results for =CONCATENATE("format: ",CELL("format",J4), " type: ", CELL("type",J4))?

Since you are the one preparing the Excel on the server, just save/copy the date values as dates and not as text strings. Dates are stored as numbers and would be properly interpreted as the correct date no matter the regional settings.

@nkalvi Sure, here are the results:
Server: 'format: G type: l'
Local: 'format: D1 type: l'

Thanks  Raphaël. I assume it is same file you opened in both places; though the type is text constant in both, I'm not sure why it is interpreted general on the server and as date locally. D1 means "d-mmm-yy or dd-mmm-yy", by using CELL you may be able to improve the formula.

Since the value of J4 is a string value, Excel is implicitly converting the value to a date in the EOMONTH function. The implicit conversion on the server is using the American regional settings. The implicit conversion on the local machine is using the British regional settings.
One possible solution is to use string manipulation and assume the source will always be in an American date format.
Try this:
= EOMONTH( DATE( VALUE( RIGHT( J4, 4 ) )
               , VALUE( LEFT( J4, 2 ) )
               , VALUE( MID( J4, 4, 2 ) ) ), 0 )


This was an effective workaround for me
